# How can I correct this Google Sheets script error?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to sync Form responses in a Google Sheet to a shared calendar but I am getting the following error every time I run the script.  It does create an event and sync the data, but the error does not allow it to automatically trigger when a form is submitted.

Exception: The parameters (String,String,String) don't match the method signature for CalendarApp.Calendar.createEvent.
myFunction  @ Code.gs:17

Here is the code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("O2").getValue();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);


  var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("W2:Y2000").getValues();

for (x=0; x<signups.length; x++) {

  var shift = signups[x];

  var startTime = shift[0];
  var endTime = shift[1];
  var volunteer = shift[2];

  eventCal.createEvent(volunteer, startTime, endTime);
  
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the datestring into `date` in your script

```js
  var startTime = new Date(shift[0]);
  var endTime = new Date(shift[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I am now getting the following error:                                                                                                                                               Exception: You have been creating or deleting too many calendars or calendar events in a short time. Please try again later.
myFunction @ Code.gs:17

Comment: See [Exception messages](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#exception_messages). It suggests to Try `Utilities.sleep(1000)` between calls.